# Bonjour java: Finding the address of a service that belongs to a specific network interface

Tags: java, dns-sd

I'm trying to find the address that matches a resolved Bonjour service that is registered to a specific network interface.

DNSSD gives me the `hostname` and the network interface index of a service: `ifIndex`. If  the host has multiple network interfaces, I have to find out which of the network interfaces belongs to the `ifIndex` that this service is registered to (assuming that the service's `ifIndex` is not 0 or -1).

```
public void serviceResolved(DNSSDService resolver, int flags, int ifIndex, String fullName, String hostName, int port, TXTRecord txtRecord) {
    InetAddress[] addresses = null;
    try {
        addresses = InetAddress.getAllByName(hostName);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {}

    for (InetAddress address : addresses) {
        //How do I know what the appropriate address is?
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to find out which of the ip addresses of the resolved `hostname` belongs to the resolved `ifIndex`?

Many thanks,
Mattijs